# Почему POST запрос не возвращает нужные данные?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь получить данные с [этой страницы.](https://vstup.edbo.gov.ua/)

С помощью Chrome DevTools обнаружил что после нажатие на кнопку "Пошук" отправляется POST запрос с параметрами, и приходит ответ с нужными данными в виде JSON.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Следуя советам из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request) решил написать простую программу для получения данных путем отправки POST запроса.

Вот мой код:

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        SendPost();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void SendPost()
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "action", "universities" },
            { "university-id", "" },
            { "qualification", "1" },
            { "education-base", "40" },
            { "speciality", "122" },
            { "program", "" },
            { "education-form", "" },
            { "course", "" },
            { "region", "" },
            { "university-name", "" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(@"https://vstup.edbo.gov.ua", content);

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
}
```

Однако вместо данных в виде JSON в ответе я получаю лишь пустые фигурные скобки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? И как мне получить нужные мне данные?

Comment: Вы что то упускаете. Дам подсказку, это заголовок, ссылка. Ну а вообще, я бы закрыл как дубликат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы думаете на сайте присутствует авторизация с помощью передаваемого заголовка cookies? Я тоже раньше так думал, и решил заблокировать cookies на этом сайте с помощью Chrome. И после этого заголовок cookies перестал передаваться (как видно из скриншота в вопросе), однако данные как возвращались так и возвращаются в виде JSON. Так что если я правильно понимаю авторизации на сайте нету. Если я не правильно понял ваш комментарий и речь идет о каком то другом заголовке, дайте знать пожалуйста.

Comment: Куки != заголовок. Почитайте внимательней тот ответ и посмотрите как отлавливать нужные заголовки, как очищать лишнее, какой инструментарий для этого стоит использовать и так далее. Хорошо, с подсказками вы плохо дружите, больше конкретики - Установите заголовок `Referer`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ответ, добавление к запросу заголовка Referer решило мою проблему, теперь данные возвращаются. Уже качаю fiddler для того чтобы лучше разобраться в вопросе. Это мой первый вопрос на StackOverflow, не подскажите как лучше с ним поступить? Отметить его как дубликат с ссылкой на ваш ответ, или самому написать ответ и обозначить его как правильный, или дать вам возможность ответить и обозначить ваш ответ как решение?

Comment: Это уже решать вам. Если вы уверены, что предложенный мной дубликат решает вашу задачу, то закрывайте им, если нет - пишите ответ сами. По поводу Fiddler - В 80% случаев достаточно и хрома, вы главное поставьте Postman и через него играйтесь с запросом, а не сразу пишите код. Все же Postman - это самая необходимая программа для решения таких задач.